# How to workaround 'data' attribute missing in Angular when it is build of static part and variable?

Tags: angular

I have a couple of template tags in Angular like that:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="api/swfgames/{{ game.id }}.swf" width="{{ game.width }}" height="{{ game.height }}">
   <param name="movie" value="api/swfgames/{{ game.id }}.swf"/>
   <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
   <!--<img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" crossorigin="anonymous" alt="Get Adobe Flash player"/>-->Get Flash!</a>
</object>
```

and to investigate I have tried variable-less approach to `object` tag with the variable value hard-coded.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="api/swfgames/1052.swf" width="260" height="23">
```

And I get it rendered as

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" id="myFlashMovie" width="730" height="605" align="middle"> <param name="movie" value="api/swfgames/1052.swf">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="730" height="605">
        <param name="movie" value="api/swfgames/1052.swf">  
        <br>
        <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash"> Get Flash!</a>
    </object>
</object>
```

(note there is no `data` attribute for the inner `object` tag there; also note width and height that are successfully renedered of the variable)
and

```
<object data="api/swfgames/1052.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="260" height="23">
```

(note there the `data` attribute exists and make the tag workig)

How I can force `data` attribute to be rendered as concatenation of the static string and the variable?

UPD

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="{{ 'api/swfgames/' +  game.id }}.swf" width="{{ game.width }}" height="{{ game.height }}">
```

also doesn't help; more this part is always highlighted as 'can't resolve directory'

[image]

UPD2. And the same doesn't work even with `<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src='{{ "api/swfgames/" +  game.id + ".swf" }}' width="{{ game.width }}" height="{{ game.height }}"/>`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xyjwxl is the same on the stackblitz

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32183 the issue was closed. should using of sanized url help for this case?